Strange optimizer behavior
I was trying to solve the problem of cracking Kid-RSA with brute force (I know we can use the extended Euclidean algorithm).
The problem is that the example task used 64 bits numbers and in order to take the product and then compute the modulus, I need the high 64 bits of the product. MSVC doesn't support __int128, but x64 assembly does, so I used two intrinsics to access the high part of the multiplication and to perform the 128 bits division:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <intrin.h>

int main()
{
    uint64_t e = 17459243613;            // public key
    uint64_t n = 66624478857659;         // public key
    uint64_t m = 0x7fafffbffcffdfff / e; // m is a random value that will fit 64 bits when multiplied by e  
    uint64_t c = e * m % n;              // encripted m

    for (uint64_t d = 1; d < n; ++d) {
        // r = c * d % n; // Doesn't work!

        // Multiply and divide using 128 bits
        uint64_t r = 0; 
        _udiv128(__umulh(c, d), c * d, n, &r); 

        if (r == m) {
            printf("Solution: %"PRIu64"\n", d);
            break;
        }
    }
}

Looking at the generated assembly I noticed that the optimizer was doing a strange operation (comments are mine):
; rcx is d (starts from 1), r9 is c, r8 (starts from c)
for_loop:
        mov     rax, rcx       ; d -> rax
        mul     r9             ; rax*c -> rdx:rax
        mov     rax, r8        ; <-- This is the strange operation
        div     r10            ; rdx:rax % n -> rdx
        cmp     rdx, 526990399 ; 
        je      print_solution ; if (rdx == m) goto print_solution
        inc     rcx            ; ++d
        add     r8, r9         ; r8 += c <-- This is together with the other
        cmp     rcx, r10       ;
        jb      for_loop       ; if (d < n) goto for_loop

This made me realize that if you multiply c times d with d constantly increasing, you can just increment the current value by c at every iteration without need for the multiplication at all (because we are working modulus n).
It looks as if the optimizer somehow realized it, but failed to get the optimization right and left a partial optimization in the code which is in fact useless: everything would have worked perfectly without those two instructions.
Can you comment on this? Is my understanding correct? Are the two instructions indeed useless?
Side note: on my PC this takes 13 minutes to find the solution, while using r = (r + c) % n; takes 5 minutes.

Something like this should also be sufficient: r+=c; r= r>=n?r-n:r since after adding c once r can't increase by more than n.

@chtz Wow! 54 seconds. That's definitely smarter then my division.

@chtz 30 seconds if you remove intermediate output (which was not significant when it run for 13 minutes).

To me it looks like the compiler only figured out that it can compute the lower half of c*d by increasing r8 every iteration by r9. But it apparently does not see how this interacts with __umulh and _udiv128.
